# Dan Grossman Daterange Picker

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, date-range, daterangepicker

I have a strange behavior on the date range picker from dan grossman (based on bootstrap).

It works fine except on very small browsers like mobile : the datepickers are one above the other, that's ok. But the Start date is BELOW the and date and it's a little bit confusing.

Tried various css hack but couldn't get rid of it...

http://jsfiddle.net/XxwSZ/61/

```
<div id="daterange" >
    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
    <span>My date range</span>
</div>

 $("#daterange").daterangepicker();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add this jquery function just for small screen resolutions (e.g. if screen width smaller than 768px):

```
var width = $(window).width();
if ((width < 768)) {
    $(".calendar.right").insertAfter(".calendar.left");
}
```